# Tabulator - get another cell's value on click event

Tags: tabulator

this one should be simple for tabulator experts (but not for me)...

i have a tabulator table. I've made one column, "edit" clickable as shown below. it works fine and returns the value of the cell i clicked. HOWEVER, that's not what i need. I need to get the value of ANOTHER cell in the same row (column "transactionID"). I know how you would do it in other languages, just use x and y values to move over 3 columns and get the value. but how is it done in tabulator? by the cloumn name? I can't find any example code on how to accomplish this.

This is the snippet from my tabulator init :

`{title:"edit" , name:"edit", formatter:myformatter, cellClick:function(e, cell){alert("cell clicked - " + cell.getValue())}},`

i just need to make it return value for "transactionID" instead of "edit"

and before anyone asks, no, i can't just make "transactionID" clickable. I need the clickable cell to be separate.

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so since i got no answers to this question, i slogged thru and figured it out myself eventually. To save others time who run into this in the future, i am posting how i solved it. code with comments below :

```
// this goes in your tabulator column definitions. In my example, "edit" is a column
 with an image button that on clicking, redirects to another page depending on what cell was clicked

{title:"" , name:"edit", formatter:openIcon, headerSort:false, cellClick:function(e, cell){
         
         
         var re = cell.getRow(cell); // get the row of the cell that was clicked
         var thenum = re.getData().id; // gets the value of column "id" in the same row
         var theurl = "editTransaction.php?trans="+thenum; // creates my url
         console.log(theurl); // perform whatever action you need to do. replace this.
         
         
         
         }},
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-tabulator and you want to access some column data to perform a specific action ,here is the snippet for your help.

```
import { reactFormatter } from "react-tabulator";
// your React Component to use in a cell
function CustomFormatter(props: any) {   
  const rowData = props.cell._cell.row.data;
  return <a onClick={() => alert(rowData.customField)}{cellData.customField }</a>;
}
const columns = [{ title: 'Custom', field: 'custom', align: 'center', formatter: reactFormatter(<CustomFormatter />) },
]
```